# Simple database for Windows 8

Tags: c#, database, windows, sqlite, windows-8

I'm looking for simple database compatible with metro apps. I thought that sqlite would be ok but I must support ALL windows8 versions. Is there a good solution for this problem or I must use some txt files?

Comment: "ALL Windows 8 versions" - does this include Windows RT for ARM processors?

Comment: Don't you see the news ?? Don't use the word "metro" !!!

Comment: SQLite supports ARM now.  See http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2012/08/07/updated-how-to-using-sqlite-from-windows-store-apps.aspx

Comment: Yeah, sure - Error 1 The processor architecture of the project being built "Any CPU" is not supported by the referenced SDK "Microsoft.VCLibs, Version=11.0". Please consider changing the targeted processor architecture of your project (in visual studio this can be done through the Configuration Manager) to one of the architectures supported by the SDK: "x86, x64, ARM".

Answer (score 0):

We use IndexedDB. Find more information here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/IndexedDB

Answer (score 0):

You should look at using Windows Storage. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br227346.aspx http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br230302%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#storage

If you have experience of Windows Phone 7 then it is not dissimilar to Isolated storage.

There are other options detailed here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663264(v=vs.85).aspx